# Unable to access ssrs reports from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have deployed ssrs report on a machine with Win 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2. And i am trying to access those reports from ASP.NET application deployed on the same machine. I am able to access the reports from URL from configuration tool. But when i access the same from deployed ASP.NET application it throws "Unauthorized" error. The application is developed in environment with Win XP, SQL Server 2008. I have so many possibility i noticed from internet. But don't know come to know what i am missing to access the report from ASP.NET application.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the implementation?

Comment: Please let me know i you need some diffrent solution or your case is diffrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code on Page_Load event and include using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;:
Remote mode is needed when report is on diffrent server:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(rptServerUrl);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath ="Exact Report Path Here";
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials(userId, password, domain);
        }`
```